# How to export object as multiple meshes?

Tags: export

I made a character with a skeleton that needs to be exported as an .FBX to Unreal Engine 4. There are multiple objects in the hierarchy that make up the full object. I need these objects to export in one file, but as seperate objects so I can texture each on individually. I could texture the objects in blender, but the materials are already premade and cannot be exported from UE4. How could I export them as one file, but able to edit each individual object in the engine?

Comment: Is your character currently one object?

Comment: No, it's made up of multiple different objects.

Comment: Use Batex plugin. which can be obtained here: https://www.blendernation.com/2019/08/15/blender-2-8-free-batch-export-addon/